# Rails: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migrate

```
class CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :admin_users_pages2, :id => false  do |t|
      t.integer "admin_user_id"
      t.integer "page_id"
    end
    add_index :admin_users_pages2 ["admin_user_id", "page_id"]
  end

  def down
    drop_table :admin_users_pages2
  end
end
```

When i run rake db:migrate
It gets aborted and gives the following error:
 no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you run `rake db:migrate` from scratch?

Comment: also what is to do with `[5.0]`?

Comment: Please format your question properly so that it's readable. Use the { } in the format bar to mark formatted code.

Comment: Run `rake db:migrate` with `--trace` option. `rake db:migrate --trace` which gives you more info on where exactly it is erroring out.

Answer (score 3):

```
class CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :admin_users_pages2, :id => false  do |t|
      t.integer "admin_user_id"
      t.integer "page_id"
    end
    add_index :admin_users_pages2, ["admin_user_id", "page_id"]
  end

  def down
    drop_table :admin_users_pages2
  end
end
```

You had missed comma for add_index line.